# Hibernate issue with mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

Please see this code. I have 1 to many relationship between Branch and Customer. I keep getting this error message, but can't figure out what the problem is. Here is the exception:

```
    org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:     com.bank.entity.Branch column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

BRANCH CLASS

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Branch")
public class Branch extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "branch")
private Set<Customer> customers;
}
```

CUSTOMER CLASS

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customer")
public class Customer extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "branchId", nullable = false)
private Branch branch;
}
```

I have tried inserting updateable=false, insertable=false in different places but keep getting the error. Any suggestions woiuld be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is that the complete code of the entities? What's the code of AbstractPersistable<Long>?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes thanks you for the help. Just up voted and accepted your answer now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractPersistable.html).

Since you are using **AbstractPersistable**, there is no need to specify "**id**" attribute in you entity class. Either do no extend "**AbstractPersistable**" or remove "**id**" from your classes. It should work then.